# How to call gdaltransform with its input?

Tags: python, gdal

I want to convert between different coordinates. If I'm in the command line, it's as simple as:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32616
-122 46
```

And I receive the output

```
-2193988.77788563 5724599.39928024 0
```

I'm trying to use this in a python program, and it seems like I need the input in the same command. Something like this (although it doesn't work)

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -122 46 -t_srs EPSG:32616
```

In my python program, I have tried to make separate calls:

```
command = "gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:" + data['crs']
os.system(command)
command = data['lon'] + ' ' + data['lat']
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

but get an error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '-122 46' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I'm not sure of the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in Python without a call to an external process using the GDAL python bindings.

Here's an example:

```
from osgeo import osr

src = osr.SpatialReference()
tgt = osr.SpatialReference()
src.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
tgt.ImportFromEPSG(int(data['crs']))

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(src, tgt)
coords = transform.TransformPoint(-122, 46)
x,y = coords[0:2]
```

Comment: First call I received an error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` because my crs was using UTM, so I added the transform variables to `x,y,z` and it worked! 

I'm new to GIS, will this work for any reference system? Like for EPSG:32616 I needed to add the `z` var. Are there any other crs that require more than 3 vars?

Comment: @amallard not sure when z will be returned, but don't think there is ever more than x, y & z. See edit.

Comment: As of GDAL 3.0 a transformation may return X, Y, Z & time values.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -122 46 -t_srs EPSG:32616`  or `gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32616 -122 46` doesn't work because the coordinates are read by the program itself from its stdin and not the shell (I have to press Enter before entering the coordinates, look at [Multiple line shell commands using Python commands module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15884290))

```
$ gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32616 -122 46
Usage: gdaltransform [--help-general]
[-i] [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]
[-order n] [-tps] [-rpc] [-geoloc] 
[-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]*
[srcfile [dstfile]]
FAILURE: Unknown option name '-122'
```

and

```
$ gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32616
-122 46
-2193988.77788563 5724599.39928024 0
```

or

```
$ echo -122 46 | gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32616
-2193988.77788563 5724599.39928024 0
```

Therefore, in my case

```
import subprocess
command = ["gdaltransform", "-s_srs", "EPSG:4326", "-t_srs", "EPSG:32616", "-122", "46"]
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

raise an error

But

```
cmd = 'echo {} {} | gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:{}'.format(-122, 46, 32616)
print subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True),
-2193988.77788563 5724599.39928024 0
```

or

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['gdaltransform', '-s_srs', 'epsg:4326', '-t_srs', 'epsg:32616'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate("%s %s" % (-122, 46))[0]
-2193988.77788563 5724599.39928024 0
```