# Python GDAL convert vertical raster point

Tags: python, gdal, epsg

The following command allows me to convert from height above geoid to height above ellipsoid:

```sh
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326+5773 -t_srs EPSG:4979
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
10 20  
10 20 26.504430770874
```

How can I do this in python? I tried the following, but the source reference datum didn't work:

```py
from osgeo import osr

src = osr.SpatialReference()
tgt = osr.SpatialReference()
src.ImportFromEPSG(4326+5773) # ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found
tgt.ImportFromEPSG(4979)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(src, tgt)
coords = transform.TransformPoint(20, 10)
print(coords)
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226200/how-to-call-gdaltransform-with-its-input

Comment: Looks like gdal doesn't support that CRS compounding method anymore. Check the blue note from this article: https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/10/26/convert-between-orthometric-and-ellipsoidal-elevations-using-gdal/

Comment: thanks @Zman, do you know why mikewatt's answer (and my original `gdaltransform` command worked if CRS compounding isn't supposed to work anymore?

Comment: That was the the only article that I could find talking about the deprecated format. Maybe double check with version of `gdal` you are using. Also, do you get any `User Warnings`? Wonder if anyone else could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SetFromUserInput()` instead, this is likely what parses the input on the command line:

```
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetFromUserInput('epsg:4326+5773')
print(srs)
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! I'm curious, is there another way to do this? Like if I always want the reference to be `epsg:4326+5773`, is there some sort of single identifier I can use for this?

Comment: I am confused with what you are asking...just leave it as `epsg:4326+5773` and it wont change. If you are using a function, for that parameter set is like `def function(..., input_crs=str(epsg:4326+5773))` or `def function(..., input_crs='epsg:4326+5773')`. Then if you want to change it call: `funtion(..., input_crs='epsg:####+####')`